# Установка ArchLinux - не удается установить пакеты

Tags: linux, unix, archlinux

Ставлю на виртуалку VirtualBox Arch. Делаю по [этому мануалу](https://ziggi.org/ustanovka-i-nastroyka-arch-linux-xfce-chast-1/). Дойдя до пункта "Установка пакетов", столкнулся с ошибкой "Failed to install packages to new root " после ввода команды "pacstrap -i /mnt base base-devel". Все сервера, которые прописаны в /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist возвращают ошибку 403. Вот скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заходил через браузер выборочно на сервера из "mirrorlist", сервера работают нормально.
Соединение с интернетом работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пойму, в чем проблема.

Comment: сертификаты? локальное время? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Package_signing#Cannot_import_keys

Comment: временная зона установлена правильно

Comment: а само время точное?

Comment: в приведенной мною ссылке есть еще несколько проблем, которые могут привести к данной ошибке: 1) *An outdated archlinux-keyring package.* 2) *Incorrect date.* 3) *Your ISP blocked the port used to import PGP keys.* 4) *Your pacman cache contains copy of unsigned packages from previous attempts.* 5) `dirmngr` *is not correctly configured*

Comment: Попробуй при установке пропустить пункт настройки зеркал.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выполнить синхронизацию базы данных пакетов:

```
pacman -Sy
```